# How to make custom Enum template using openapi-generator-cli@2.5.2

Tags: configuration, resttemplate, mustache, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I have global installation of @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli@2.5.2 and as additional property I use enumPropertyNaming=UPPERCASE

The --addittional-properties, given by documentation https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-rxjs/ are:'camelCase', 'PascalCase', 'snake_case', 'UPPERCASE', and 'original'

During the compilation a lot of errors come. The compilator complains because of the Enums, implemented in the frond-end.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNzEt.png)

Looking into Enums generated by my openapi gererator I see [UPPERCASE with underscore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goYhs.png)

I need customization of this result.
ONLINE_SINCE_PERIOD_EXCEEDED_ERROR should be ONLINESINCEPERIODEXCEEDEDERROR

I chose enumPropertyNaming=UPPERCASE as additional property and I was expecting to have my Enums without underscore
My backend uses snake_case for the Enums and my previous version of the openapi library created them in the way(UpperCase without underscore) which I currently what to achieve

I also have a lot of .mustache files coming with the new library, including modelEnum.mustache
[Enum mustache template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMhS4.png)

What should I do to make underscore deleted and to use this adjusted Enum

Answer (score 0):

All of the mustache templates have access to [lambda functions](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/templating.md#mustache-lambdas).  However, not every generator has access to every lambda.  You can view all the possible lambdas [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/templating/mustache) and where they are added in the code [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/DefaultCodegen.java#L440).  If you want to change your templates to use a different case, they can be implemented via the lambda interface in the mustache template.  For example, you can see how the typeScript generator's `auth.mustache` uses lambdas [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/typescript/auth/auth.mustache#L41). In that example, which looks like this `{{#lambda.pascalcase}}{{name}}{{/lambda.pascalcase}}`, the incoming name variable is converted to PascalCase using the available lambda function.  It wouldn't be too hard to update your mustache to make use of a similar lambda.

However, luckily for you, the Typescript generator is one of the only generators that allows you to configure which lambda to use without the need of touching the mustache templates.  Simply configure the `configOption` for [`EnumPropertyNaming`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/typescript-rxjs.md#:%7E:text=Enum-,enumPropertyNaming,-Naming%20convention%20for) to use the desired case.  It appears you are looking to use `PascalCase` as the property, which should be the default.  So, I'm guessing it is already configured in your cli command (or config file, I can't know since you didn't provide your generator command) to use `snake_case`.

Comment: As I understand the question, this is not about snake_case or PascalCase, but about two different flavors of UPPERCASE. Conventionally, UPPERCASE has underscores as word separators just like snake_case. The asker wants to concatenate the words back to back.

Comment: lambda doesn't work. I tried 
export enum {{classname}}{{enumName}} {
{{#allowableValues}}
    {{#enumVars}}
     {{#lambda.lowercase}}{{name}}{{/lambda.lowercase}}={{{value}}}{{^-last}},{{/-last}}
    {{/enumVars}}
{{/allowableValues}}
}
{{/isEnum}}
{{/vars}}
{{/hasEnums}}

How can I use function in {{#enumVars}} template

Comment: the openapi-generator command is:
call openapi-generator-cli generate -g typescript-rxjs --enable-post-process-file  --additional-properties=supportsES6=true,enumPropertyNaming=UPPERCASE,modelPropertyNaming=camelCase,paramNaming=camelCase,npmVersion=8.3.1 --global-property models=CreateGatewayResponse -o src/api/ -i http://localhost:8081/ui/v3/api-docs

Answer (score 0):

I found an official link about secret params:

```
WeatherType:
  type: integer
  format: int32
  enum:
    - 42
    - 18
    - 56
  x-enum-descriptions:
    - 'Blue sky'
    - 'Slightly overcast'
    - 'Take an umbrella with you'
  x-enum-varnames:
    - Sunny
    - Cloudy
    - Rainy
```

Yes! the secret: **x-enum-varnames** works!

I think it is absurd to do upcase or lowcase for enum types, because enum means it is countable. just copy & pasles all the possibles! **if you cannot do so, it is must be a general string type.**

ref: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/templating.md#enum